# Is it possible to copy the version history of NodeRef in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am new in Alfresco, hope someone could explain to me some open questions that I have.
Imagine that we have one base NodeRef. What if I create a duplicates (copies) of that base Node.
Can we copy all the versions from **version history** from that base NodeRef to the duplicates?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no [method on VersionService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/AlfrescoOne/5.0/PublicAPI/org/alfresco/service/cmr/version/VersionService.html) to do directly that. Have you tried just getting the Version History then effectively re-playing that on the new node?

Comment: @Gagravarr - I thought to do that, and I have tried, but for some reason it won't work, maybe something I am doing wrong. Can you give me a hint what to use for that? Thanks!

Comment: Post the code you're trying and I can see if I can spot the issue!

Comment: What is your goal by trying to clone a node incl. version history? Maybe it's better to work with secondary child assocs to reference the same node in more than one directory?